# Impulse response of LTI Systems

Tags: fourier-transform, impulse-response, pulse

I am trying to solve these questions. I have attached my solutions. Please I would appreciate if some one can check my approach and tell me if I am correct or not. Also, how can I proceed to find $h_0(t)$?

---

**Question (s) with My Attempts**

1. Given the LTI-System with frequency response $$\LARGE H(j\omega)=T_1e^{-\frac{j\omega T_1}{2}}\cdot\frac{\sin(\frac{\omega T_1}{2})}{\frac{\omega T_1}{2}}$$Find
   a. Impulse Response $h_0(t)$ of this system.
   b. Reaction $y(t)$ of this system to the input signal $\Gamma(t)$

   [image]

---

2. Determine the Fourier Transform of the Rectangular Pulse shown in the following figure. 
   [image] 
   [image]

Comment: Your calculation is correct, but I think it will not lead to a simple solution (You'd need to calculate inverse FT of (1/jw), which does converge in the common sense, I think.) Instead, I give you two hints: 1) Check out the time-shift property of the FT and apply it to your equation. 2) Remember the what the Fourier transform of a rectangular function is and try to apply it here. Let us know, if you can solve on your own now or need more help, explaining your problems with my hints.

Comment: Maximilian, thanks very much for the tips. I am trying to apply the Inverse FT but I am confuse on how to simply it.

Comment: I didn't check your calculations, but $\frac{2}{j\omega}$ is the FT of sgn function. So you actually have a difference of a sgn and a shifted sgn by $T$ which **is** a box function (width of $T$). However, a DC value is missing (compared to the IFT of the sinc). So some delta should also be there in your result...

Comment: I have tried to do some maths manipulation which I have attached above, i don't know if I am on the right track.

Comment: @msm: You are right with the signs, but I think actually solving this integral is not easly. Further, I dont think there is a DC missing, the IFT of a sinc is also just a box.

Comment: @Soso: Can you perform the inverse FT of $\frac{sin(\omega \frac{T}{2})}{\omega\frac{T}{2}}$? if you can do this, you have actually solved the problem, using the time-shifting property of the FT. Have a look at a correspondence table of the Fourier Transform.

Comment: @Maximilian: the inverse FT if the said function is like inverse FT of a sinc function which is a rectangular function

Comment: @Soso: right. final hint: for any FT pair $X(jw)=\mathcal{F}\{x(t)\}$ (i.e. $X(jw)$ is the FT of $x(t)$.) What is $\mathcal{F}\{x(t-t_0)\}$?

Comment: F{x(t-t0)} = X(w)exp(-jwt0)

Comment: Now apply both rules to your problem. You will not need to solve a single integral.

Comment: @Maximilian: Thanks very much. So it is like a shifted rectangular function: rect(t - T1/2)

Comment: Yes, in principle. Take care of the width of the rectangle and of the amplitude. Especially the amplitude is something that can easily go wrong. But, if I were the supervisor, I would consider more important that you were able to see that you can apply the correspondence sinc<->rect and the time-shift property rather than punishing, if the amplitude of the rect was wrong. Though, the width of the rect is important.

Comment: @Maximilian: Thank you very much. I have tried to derive the H(jw) from the answer of h(t). I got the exact expression as you can see above

Comment: @MaximilianMatthé I also agree that this is not the straightforward approach. The DC value I was talking about is because difference of two sgns is symmetric with respect to the $x$-axis (has zero mean). While a rectangular box (inverse of sinc) is above $x$-axis and has DC.

Comment: @msm well, I'm not sure, if this is correct. I fully agree that the mean of a sign-function is zero. However, I think the box-function actually also has zero-mean (which sounds not intuitive initially). There are two arguments for this: 1) The integral $\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^{T}t\text{rect}(t)dt=0$. 2) The mean of a sign is zero. The mean of -sign is zero. The sum of two zero-mean functions is the sum of their means.

Comment: @MaximilianMatthé Totally agreed. But the mean (over interval $T$) is usually defined as $\frac{1}{T}\int_T f(t) dt$. So in this case $\frac{1}{T}\int_T \mathrm{rect}(\frac{t}T) dt$ which is one for $T=1$.

Answer (score 6):

$h_0(t)$ is inverse Fourier transform of $H(jw)$. Your formula is OK, you can continue your calculation to practice your math manipulation, why not.
To check the result, you can remark that $H(jw)$ is rotated $sinc$ function. And $sinc$ must be the Fourier transform of a rectangular box function.

Comment: So it is like a shifted rectangular function: rect(t - T1/2)